# axwindowsmediaplayer is showing green page instead of playing video in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am developing a wpf application for a low performance system (on board VIA/S3G UniChrome Pro IGP graphic with 16 MB Memory size). Application works in an information kiosk showing images in slide mode or playing videos base on schedules made by operator. Main application is by wpf(.net 3.5) and I used axwindowsmediaplayer activex for playing videos inside a popup winform (topmost=true;maximazed).

My problem is: Sometimes when application wants to play a video, axwindowsmediaplayer shows a green page and doesn't play video.(it doesn't happen always)
doese anyone have any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909554) from back in 2005 seems to point to video card issues (outdated drivers in particular).